# How to install Anaconda while having this error?

Tags: download, anaconda3

I need to install Anaconda for some works but the downloading is failing everytime i try.
The error i get when i press the "show details" button is :

"Output folder: C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\conda-meta
Extract: history

Downloading and Extracting Packages

Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... WARNING conda.core.envs_manager:register_env(49): Unable to register environment. Path not writable or missing.
environment location: C:\ProgramData\anaconda3
registry file: C:\Users\lance.conda\environments.txt

Windows 64-bit packages of scikit-learn can be accelerated using scikit-learn-intelex.
More details are available here: https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex

```
For example:

    $ conda install scikit-learn-intelex
    $ python -m sklearnex my_application.py
```

done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(740): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::debugpy-1.6.7-py311hd77b12b_0'."

Also a pop up window appears saying there is an error while the linking of the package and that i need to check logs...

I have tried :
-uninstall reinstall
-launching while executing as administrator
-change the file location

I also uninstalled the installed files although the download never succeeded

thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Posting this in case someone has the same problem.

after a last attempt, i finally found the problem. It seems that Hp Sure Sense was blocking some of the files/packages i was trying to downlaod.

For me, Hp Sure Sense is unfoundable on the task manager. The only way to shut it is : Settings -> apps and features -> search for Hp Sure Sense (for me it was Hp Sure Sense Installer ?? i don't know why it works) -> uninstall (even if it is written installer)
try to install again anaconda and it will works